# How to handle branching Promises in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, es6-promise, typescript-typings

I'm trying to type the following promise in TypeScript:

```
const getUserById = (id: number) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => id === 1
    ? resolve({ id, displayName: 'Jan' })
    : reject('User not found.')
);
```

TypeScript infers this as

```
const getUserById: (id: number) => Promise<Unknown>
```

I have an interface for the user:

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  displayName: string;
}
```

Is there any way to have the function `getUserbyId` recognize that it can either resolve with a `User` or reject with a `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Typescript is having trouble inferring it, you can give arrow functions an explicit return type. Typescript will tell you if the type you give it doesn't match what actually happens, so you don't have the same concerns as casting.

```
const getUserById = (id: number): Promise<User> => new Promise((resolve, reject) => id === 1
    ? resolve({ id, displayName: 'Jan' })
    : reject('User not found.')
);
```

Comment: Hi ben, thank you very much! But doesn't TypeScript now think it could resolve with either a string or a `User`? Whereas in reality, it can only resolve with a `User` and reject with a string?

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you again. So is there no way for TypeScript to know that this function will reject with a string?

Comment: Correct, the reject type is [hard coded](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7588#issuecomment-198700729) to `any`. You can test for the type in your catch block though, if that's important.

Comment: Slightly shorter `const getUserById = (id: number) => new Promise<User>((resolve, reject) ...`

Answer (score 0):

To get a deeper understanding, you can have a look the type definition for Promise constructor:

`declare type PromiseConstructorLike = new <T>(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void) => PromiseLike<T>;`

As you can see it takes only one generic type `T`, which referring to the **resolve** value type, and it has nothing to do with reject type (always `any`).

That's why it can not infer the resolve type to be `User | string`.